# Range of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}} $$
$$ y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}} $$
For range, we can rewrite the equation so that we have an expression for $x$ in terms of $y$, and then see all values that $y$ can take.

$$ y^2 = \frac{1}{16-x^2} $$
$$ \frac{1}{y^2} = 16 - x^2 $$
$$ x^2 = 16-\frac{1}{y^2} $$

From this, we know that:
$$16-\frac{1}{y^2} \ge 0         \tag 1\\$$

Here:
$$\frac{1}{y^2} \le 16 $$
$$ y^2 \ge \frac{1}{16} $$ (The inequality reverses when taking reciprocal)

So,
$$y \in \left(-\infty,-\frac{1}{4}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{4},\infty \right)$$

But looking at our original function, we know that $y$ will never be negative as the $\sqrt{}$ function will only yield positive values. From this we can easily get the range of the function.

But, at $(1)$, if we write this as:

$$\frac{1}{y^2} - 16 \le 0 $$

$$\left(\frac{1}{y} + 4\right)\left(\frac{1}{y} - 4\right) \le 0$$

From this, we know that for the product of two binomials to be negative, *one and only one* of the two should be negative.

Now, we can consider two conditions:

1. $\left(\frac{1}{y} + 4\right) \ge 0$ AND $\left(\frac{1}{y} - 4\right) \le 0$

Simplifying the former:

$$\frac{1}{y} \ge -4   $$
$$y \le -\frac{1}{4}  \tag 2\\$$ (Reciprocal --> Reversing inequality)

Now, simplifying the latter:

$$\frac{1}{y} \le 4$$
$$y \ge \frac{1}{4}     \tag 3\\$$

But, we know that $(2)$ and $(3)$ cannot both be true together, so we can ignore this pair of inequalities.

2. $\left(\frac{1}{y} + 4\right) \le 0 $ AND $ \left(\frac{1}{y} - 4\right) \ge 0 $

Again, simplifying the former:

$$\frac{1}{y} \le -4$$
$$y \ge -\frac{1}{4}        \tag 4\\$$

Simplifying the latter:

$$ \frac{1}{y} \ge 4$$
$$y \le \frac{1}{4}     \tag 5\\$$

By combining (4) and (5), we see that $$y \in \left[-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right]$$

But this is clearly wrong; the correct range of this function is $$\left[\frac{1}{4},\infty\right)$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Squaring both sides of an equation can introduce extraneous solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot that $y$ is not an arbitrary real number. If it was, then, yes,$$16-\frac1{y^2}\geqslant0\iff y\in\left(-\infty,-\frac14\right]\cup\left[\frac14,\infty\right).\tag1$$But $y$ is a number of the form $\frac1{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$. This tells you right away that $y>0$. Now, it follows from $(1)$ that $y\in\left[\frac14,\infty\right)$. On the other hand, if $y\geqslant\frac14$, then\begin{align}f(x)=y&\iff\frac1{\sqrt{16-x^2}}=y\\&\iff\frac1{16-x^2}=y^2\ (\text{since $y\geqslant0$})\\&\iff x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{16y^2-1}}y.\end{align}So, yes, $y$ does belong to the range of $f$.

Comment: Why does $y \ge \frac{1}{4}$ mean $f(x) = y \iff \frac{1}{16-x^2} = y$
Why is that only true when $y$ satisfies that inequality? 
Also, what error did I make in the manipulation of the two binomials (eqs. 2, 3, 4 and 5)?

Comment: If $a,b\geqslant0$, then $a=b\iff a^2=b^2$. That's what I used here.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Although, I still don't get what error I made in the manipulation of the two binomials (eqs. 2, 3, 4 and 5)?

Comment: Since $y>0$, asserting that $\left(\frac1y+4\right)\left(\frac1y-4\right)\leqslant0$ is the same thing as asserting that $\frac1y-4\leqslant0$, which is the same thing as asserting that $y\geqslant\frac14$.

Comment: Which is what I did! Additionally though, I also added the condition that $\left(\frac{1}{y} + 4\right) \ge 0$, which obviously has to be true, so adding this condition should not change anything, _right_? Clearly it did change something, because this condition was the reason that I did not get the correct answer. What was the issue with this step?

Also, from my **second** set of conditions, I got a mathematically valid pair of conditions which gives me a completely wrong range. Clearly something went wrong, _what was it_?

Comment: The condition $\frac1y+4\leqslant0$ and $\frac1y-4\geqslant0$ *never holds*, since this means the $\frac1y$ is both smaller that or equal to $-4$ and greater than or equal to $4$.

Comment: I realize that from the result I get, but I don't get WHY those two conditions don't hold, since for their product to be negative, one HAS to be negative and the other HAS to be positive, so those conditions must hold... right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139820/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-avs).

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to check the range here

we know that $$16-x^2\le 16$$
which mean that, and since a radical is always positive,
$$\sqrt{16-x^2}\le 4$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\ge \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow y\ge 1/4$$
$$\Rightarrow y\in \left[\frac{1}{4}, +\infty\right)$$

additionally, one of the mistakes I see in your second argumet is when
$$\frac{1}{y}\ge -4$$
$$\not\Rightarrow y\le -\frac{1}{4}$$
since $y$ may be positive. For example, if $y=2$, $\frac{1}{2}\ge -4$ but $2\not\le -\frac{1}{4}$. This particular inequality manipulation generally works for strictly positive values.